# Most efficient way to lock a resource using c++11 in Windows when shared access is extremely rare?

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, winapi

I have a C++ class which contains a list of rules. One function adds/removes rules of this class, and the other one does some checking based on the rules (For example takes a PID as input, and based on the rules it would return a decision)

So I need to make sure I am not doing any checking when I'm removing/adding rules. But adding and removing rules is very rare, so 99.9% of the times that I am doing the checking, there is no need to do locking, as no one would be removing/adding rules.

**My question is**, what is the most optimal way to make sure we are not doing any checking when I'm adding or removing rules, but at the same time making sure checking is not slowed down?

I thought about just using the std::mutex and get it over with, but then I have to keep locking when doing the checking even tho 99.9% of the times there will be no need for locking, wouldn't this slow it down a lot?

I also thought about using Critical Sections, but based on some stack overflow threads, critical sections are even slower than std::mutex in windows 8.1+.

I am also OK with using WinAPIs to solve this.

Comment: One class has both functions, so can both functions be called in parallel on same object?

Comment: @kiner_shah Yes they can be called at the same time, assume for example when needing to update the rules, I would be adding/removing rules and another thread  call the checking function at the same time on the same object.

Comment: Rare or not, it's still shared. `std::mutex` is the default choice

Comment: How long does adding/removal of rules take? Is that a very slow thing to do?

Comment: @kiner_shah  No it doesnt take that long.

Comment: @Vivick But wouldnt that slow down the checking function 99.9% of the times for no reason?

Comment: Maybe use a atomic boolean flag, say isChecking. When checking function enters set it to true, when it exits set it to false. When adding/removing, check initially whether that flag is set to false, waiting until it's set to false and then adding/removing rules.

Comment: Or use condition variables which would again use a boolean flag to indicate checking status.

Comment: @kiner_shah Pretty good idea. I would actually do it the other way, using a boolean value bIsUpdating I would stop doing the checking when the update is happening, as it would not cause any issue to stop the checking during Update in my case.

Comment: I guess it can depend on the std implementation, but with MSVC I think std::mutex is implemented using a critical section. Note: on Windows a Critical Section is quite lightweight and is *not* the same as Window Mutex (names in Windows context sometimes bring confusion...)

Comment: Are you limiting yourself to C++11 specifically? Otherwise a [`shared_timed_mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_timed_mutex) (otherwise known as read-write lock) should do the trick. Note that acquiring and releasing it is a bit more expensive than a plain mutex so if your read access is extremely small, you may be better off with a normal mutex

Comment: @SimonMourier What's the deal with these threads then? Their analysis shows std mutex is faster? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997473/stdmutex-performance-compared-to-win32-critical-section

Comment: @Homer512 I think what kiner_shah suggested is even faster than that and makes sense, I would be just using atomic bools to control the access during update.

Comment: @kiner_shah's suggestion is basically a read-write spin lock, right? These tend to [have downsides and you have to be careful when hand-building them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869825/when-should-one-use-a-spinlock-instead-of-mutex). Also, it would need to be an atomic integer since multiple threads could check themselves in as readers and you can only progress as a writer when all have left. And you have to ensure no reader enters while the writer is active, probably via a special value in the atomic int

Comment: @SimonMourier I can't find the reference right now but modern MSVC mutexes are no longer built on top of critical sections. They use a virtualized interface so that the implementation can be swapped at runtime for the best available on the current windows version, e.g. [`WaitOnAddress`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160823-00/?p=94145), which is basically a better designed version of Linux's futex system call

Comment: @Homer512 - indeed, they probably have changed some time back https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/src/mutex.cpp#L74 seems they are using AcquireSRWLockExclusive

Comment: What is described is very standard situation. Experience shows that most optimal for people asking such questions is to use things from standard library.  Like that: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex  Note that usage of atomic boolean value can be horrible idea depending what you mean by "stop the checking during it being true".  Does "stopping" there mean busy-checking in cycle until it becomes false?

Comment: Have you observed/measured any unacceptable overhead from just using std::shared_mutex (reader/writer lock) from the standard library? If not don't (prematurely) optimize.

Comment: [SRW Locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/slim-reader-writer--srw--locks) probably best solution here

Comment: Just use a mutex and don't worry about it. Most likely you won't even be able to measure the overhead (and if you can *and* it's significant, *then* you can start thinking about alternatives - but not before).

Answer (score 4):

Since you are "OK with using WinAPIs to solve this", consider using a [Slim Reader/Writer Lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/slim-reader-writer--srw--locks) (Windows Vista+):

> Slim reader/writer (SRW) locks enable the threads of a single process to access shared resources; **they are optimized for speed** and occupy very little memory. Slim reader-writer locks cannot be shared across processes.
>
> Reader threads read data from a shared resource whereas writer threads write data to a shared resource. When multiple threads are reading and writing using a shared resource, exclusive locks such as a critical section or mutex can become a bottleneck **if the reader threads run continuously but write operations are rare**.
>
> SRW locks provide two modes in which threads can access a shared resource:
>
> - Shared mode, which **grants shared read-only access to multiple reader threads**, which enables them to read data from the shared resource concurrently. If read operations exceed write operations, this concurrency increases performance and throughput compared to critical sections.
> - Exclusive mode, which **grants read/write access to one writer thread at a time**. When the lock has been acquired in exclusive mode, no other thread can access the shared resource until the writer releases the lock.

When you are checking the rules, obtain the reader lock, which is very efficient and makes sure that no other thread has the writer lock.  Multiple threads can share the reader lock at the same time for concurrent read-only access.

When you are altering the rules, obtain the writer lock, which makes sure no other threads have the reader lock.  Only 1 thread can have the writer lock at a time for exclusive read/write access.

Comment: Rust ownership as a lock

Answer (score 1):

One trick I sometimes use in this situation is to make the shared object *immutable/read-only*.  If the shared object never changes, then anyone can read from it safely at any time without any locking required at all, yay!

Of course the fly in the ointment is that occasionally you *do* need to modify the shared object; however, it's immutable, so you can't.  But that's okay, because you can fake it:  first create a new (private) object that is a copy of the existing object, and then make the necessary changes to your private copy.  After all the changes you needed to do have been applied, the final step is to swap out the private/updated copy for the public/shared copy so that all the other threads can "see" the new version -- but you have to be careful how you do that, since other threads may still be reading from the existing public/shared object and you don't want to pull the rug out from under them.

The simplest way to do it would be to make sure all accesses to the shared object happen through something like a global `std::atomic<const MySharedObject *>` pointer, and just call `std::swap()` to swap out the value of that pointer.  You do need to keep the old version of the shared object around though, in case anyone is still using it even after you did the swap.

The only remaining question after that is, how long do you have to keep your old/obsolete instance(s) of the shared object around, before you can safely delete them to save memory?  The answer to that will depend a good bit on the nature of your code; you might get away with just a heuristic like "I'll assume that as of 5 seconds after the object got swapped out of public use, it will be safe to delete it".  Or you could just be super-conservative, and *never* delete the old objects, which would slowly increase memory usage but might be okay if your changes really are super-rare.

If you wanted something more formal (i.e. that doesn't rely on any questionable heuristics), you could implement some sort of feedback system, where any time one of the worker-threads notices that the value of the global-atomic-object-pointer has changed, it sends a message to your cleanup-thread to tell your cleanup-thread that it is now using the new version (and therefore no longer using the old version); then once your cleanup-thread has received that message from *all* the threads in the system, it can be 100% certain that the old object is no longer being used, and so can safely delete it.  That might be overkill for most applications, though.

Comment: `std::atomic` partially specializes `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>`, so presumably the issue of "how long do you have to keep your old/obsolete instances" is solved by "when the last reference is dropped implicitly".

Comment: @ShadowRanger that's a very good point -- using an atomic shared_ptr would take care of the whole object-disposal issue automagically.  (The only reason I didn't think of it is that the last time I implemented this, the worker-threads involved were doing hard-real-time audio tasks and therefore weren't allowed to allocate or free heap memory, and therefore I couldn't allow them to keep a copy of a shared_ptr, for fear that they would be the last to dereference an object and then end up trying to delete it themselves and blowing their time budget)

Comment: You can get around this by having a custom deleter in the `shared_ptr` that doesn't destroy but moves the object somewhere where another thread can destroy it later, e.g. put it in a lockfree linked list. Delaying the deallocation of the `shared_ptr` control structure can be done by keeping a `weak_ptr` to it around. `std::enable_shared_from_this` probably helps with that.. Still extra work for your RT thread but it is bounded to a couple atomic operations